# Regular expression for url in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am using a regular expression to validate a website address. But it is not working because its format is not correct in iPhone. Its logic is almost correct. Can anyone rebuild this regular expression for me in iPhone ?

```
(?<http>(http:[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[/.]|[~])*)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this one

```
NSString *urlRegEx =
@"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
```

Comment: Carefully with this one - it's not detecting links properly: try validate for example http://cats.org/cat-super.jpg. It breaks on "-" after first dot

Comment: I added an asnwer with improved version - if you can confirm the problem I detected and edit your answer that could help a lot of people

Answer (score 1):

use this bellow method

```
- (BOOL) validateUrl: (NSString *) stringURL {
    NSString *urlRegEx =
    @"(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx]; 
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:stringURL];
}
```

hope this help you...

:)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having problem with accepted answer regexpression here is a version I'm using:

```
(https?)://(([\\w\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\?\\<\\>])*)+([\\.|/](([\\w\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\?\\<\\>])*))+
```

The problem with accepted answer regexp is that:
\w - already contains "_" and numbers

it fails for URLs having "-" after first dot

Answer (score 1):

This will catch http / https / plain subdomain.domain.suffix links:
(Based on the good answer by Grzegorz Krukowski)

`@"((https?)://)?(([\\w\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\?\\<\\>])*)+([\\.|/](([\\w\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\?\\<\\>])+))+"`

Comment: But this will detect `km/h` or `m/sec` or something like that as URL, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this is the definitive expression:

```
NSString *URLRegEx = 
@"((https?://www[.][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9].{2,}[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})|(www[.][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9].{2,}[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,}[.][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}))";
```

Example cases in which it matches:

- http://www.example.com
- http://www.example.es
- https://www.example.com
- www.example.com
- example.com

Cases where it does not match:

- example
- http://example
- http://example.com
- www.example

etc...

If you don't want to allow all these cases, you just need to remove them from the expression.